# Create bootstrap popover buttons dynamically in ngfor

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, popover, ng-bootstrap

Hey I am trying to create bootstrap popover buttons dynamically

> Here I added ind to create different popover objects but it's not
> creating #p{{ind}}="ngbPopover" as object and when I pass this in
> function parameter I am getting a string in ts file.
>
> if I replace  #p{{ind}}="ngbPopover"  to #p1="ngbPopover" and pass
> toggleWithComponent(p1, 'c'+ind) then i am getting popover object in ts > file.

```
  <div *ngFor="let data of initialpanelDashboardInteriorInspection; let ind = index">
    <div class="img-overlay-{{ind + 1}} img-overlay">
       <button class="success-round-button round-button c{{ind}}" popoverClass="my-popvover-class" placement="bottom"
                [autoClose]="false" [ngbPopover]="popContent" [popoverTitle]="popTitle" triggers="manual"
                #p{{ind}}="ngbPopover" (click)="toggleWithComponent('p'+ind, 'c'+ind)">{{ind + 1}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So, could you just use `#p1="ngbPopover"`?

Comment: That's not a valid Angular template syntax.  What are you trying to achieve? What's the concrete problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @JBNizet i want to create dynamic popover buttons 
 for one popover we can write 
 <button class="success-round-button round-button"  popoverClass="my-popvover-class" placement="bottom" [autoClose]="false" [ngbPopover]="popContent" [popoverTitle]="popTitle" triggers="manual" #p1="ngbPopover" (click)="toggleWithComponent(p1)" >{{ind + 1}}</button> 

i want to create 5 button for 5 different popover in a for loop

Comment: Like that for example? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfnbey?file=app/popover-tplcontent.html

Comment: @JBNizet somewhat yes have one close button with click event i am passing popover object as parameter to close specific popover.
like this  toggleWithComponent(p1, 'c'+ind)
so i am trying to create that object using string concate but it is creating a string only.   #p{{ind}}="ngbPopover" to #p1="ngbPopover"

Comment: The #xxx variables are local to the loop. You don't need a new one for each iteration. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awu6gr?file=app/popover-triggers.html.

Comment: @JBNizet great it worked for me. it is possible to open one popover at a time. it this scenario